# Fast File Transfer using .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, network-protocols, zeromq

I need to transfer files from one server to multiple cients (using the internet) in the fastest possible way in .NET .
What are the different types of transfer protocols which can be used in .NET or VB.NET so that the files are sent in a very short time ?
I have tried using FTP, but that is slow because it requires authentication, handshaking etc.
What i want to know is the options which we have in .NET for sending files in the fastest possible way between a server and multiple clients.
Can we use libraries like zeromq ?

Comment: A plain [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)? Or is that to low level to you?

Comment: I think the answer to that question depends heavily on whether you want to send few big files or a lot of small files.

Comment: I would be sending a lot of small files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a TCP connection or a UDP connection. The UDP protocol is faster, but it's very unreliable, so it's good for streaming video but not for sending files you'll need to open later.

But a plain TCP connection is **not** faster than FTP, at least in my experience. FTP is the best you can get if you want reliability.

Comment: For few large files FTP is fast, for many small files it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should decide if you need TCP or UDP like Ilya suggested. 
Atfer this:

In .net you have the opportunity to copy a filestream into your networkstream (server). And from your networkstream to a filestream (client). If you have a lot of small files, you could try and zip all files to one package an transfer this one.

After the package was sent to the client you could verify a checksum (MD5 e.g.) and decompress it.